# Flex, image swap on mouse-over and state change on-click

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, onclick, mouseover

I am learning Flex and have an image I would like to changed on mouseover, and switch to another state on click.
I do not want to use any of the buttons available in Flex.
Does anyone know th code to achiev what I want?
Thanks

Comment: Any particular reason you do not want to use the available buttons? I'm asking because the proper way to do this, is by creating a custom skin for the ToggleButton class.

Comment: Hello, yes, I have created a custom button image in Illustrator that is more suited to my application theme. This is why I want to use my own image on mouse over.

Comment: It's still a bit unclear what states your button requires. Is it just 'up' and 'over' (and perhaps 'down')? Or also a 'selected' state (the button remains pressed when it is clicked and then depressed when it is clicked again)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<fx:Declarations>
  <s:BitmapImage id="imageOut" source="@Embed('images/button.png')" />
  <s:BitmapImage id="imageOver" source="@Embed('images/button-over.png')" />
</fx:Declarations>

<s:Image id="imageButton" source="{imageOut.source}"
         rollOver="imageButton.source = imageOver.source"
         rollOut="imageButton.source = imageOut.source"
         click="someObject.currentState = 'someState'"/>
```

I don't understand if you mean changing the state on the Image or on something else, but either way, this should provide a sense of how it might be done.

Comment: Hello, yes sorry I though my description might be abit abiguous, the image state wont change, I will switch the stage to a different state.

Comment: Thanks for the code I will try it. How can I get this to work for many buttons using images example home_on.jpg/home_off.jpg links_on.jpg/links_off.jpg etc

Comment: Ive managed to get it working for multiple buttons. Now I need to get the state part to work as  dont understand this yet. Say I have a state called home and a state called links. How do I switch between these using the buttons I have just created? e.g I click the links button and it loads the links state onto the stage.

Comment: @Will - A Stage object does not have states.  You probably just want to change the state of the Application, in which case, all you need is something like `click="currentState='links'"`, assuming that the button is in the MXML file that defines the top level Application.

Comment: @Will - As a side note, [Flex in a Week](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining.html) is a solid intro to programming in Flex.